# Confusion about SQL foreign key constraint when creating tables

Tags: sql, database

I have these 2 tables (I have 6 in total) that I am writing DDL for, for my class.  After searching stackoverflow and finding some examples of others experiencing my problem, I can't seem to use fix my foreign key issues while writing this script.  THe first table is created fine, the 2nd one though, which has a foreign key that points to the first table is being stubborn...I've been messing around with the syntax for the last 30 minutes or so and can't get it.  It looks like this:

```
CREATE TABLE Regional_Lot
(Regional_lot_ID    VARCHAR(10) Primary key,
location        VARCHAR(20));

Insert into Regional_Lot Values
(1,'Richmond');
Insert into Regional_Lot Values
(2,'Virginia Beach');
Insert into Regional_Lot Values
(3,'Harrisonburg');

CREATE TABLE Vehicle1
(VIN        VARCHAR(17) Primay key,
Year        VARCHAR(10),
Make        VARCHAR(10),
Model       VARCHAR(10),
Condition           VARCHAR(10),
Color       VARCHAR(10),
Transmission    VARCHAR(10),
Regional_Lot_ID VARCHAR(10) References Regional_Lot);
```

When I try to enter the 2nd table, I get an error about a missing right parenthesis which I've narrowed down through research to being a foreign key issue.

I'm also using 'Run SQL command line'.

Comment: Is the word "Primay" key a typo in your example or could that be your issue

Comment: He is inserting integer values into varchar(10) fields. My guess is he is using mysql.

Comment: Didn't even notice Primary was misspelled...I thought my syntax was off for the foreign key...thank you so much logixologist, it works now!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Syntax may vary by RDBMS, if SQL Server this should do it:

```
CREATE TABLE Vehicle1  (
           VIN             VARCHAR(17) PRIMARY KEY
          ,Year            VARCHAR(10)
          ,Make            VARCHAR(10)
          ,Model           VARCHAR(10)
          ,Condition       VARCHAR(10)
          ,Color           VARCHAR(10)
          ,Transmission    VARCHAR(10)
          ,Regional_Lot_ID VARCHAR(10) FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Regional_Lot(Regional_lot_ID)
         );
```

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE TABLE Vehicle1
(VIN        VARCHAR(17) Primay key,
Year        VARCHAR(10),
Make        VARCHAR(10),
Model       VARCHAR(10),
Condition           VARCHAR(10),
Color       VARCHAR(10),
Transmission    VARCHAR(10),
Regional_Lot_ID VARCHAR(10) foreign key References Regional_Lot(Regional_lot_ID));
```